# Twitch API : how to get _links?

Tags: c#, .net, json, stream, twitch

i use Twitch API for my project and i need to fetch the _links value on : https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ogaminglol (example)

I use this code :

```
WebClient strJson = new WebClient();
string test = strJson.DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ogaminglol");
DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Streams));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(test));
Streams stream = (Streams)js.ReadObject(ms);
//label1.Text = "Title : " + stream.game;
ms.Close();
```

And my Streams class who receive data

```
[DataContract]
class Streams
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, string> _links { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string self { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string channel { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Stream stream { get; set; }
}
```

Self and channel is null because in https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ogaminglol they are in section "_links". 
I've try Dictionary but not succes.
I hope u understand my problem (and my english :p).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here several of which could be causing the symptoms you describe:

1. Your data model does not match that of the JSON.  `self` is a property of `_links` not `Streams`.  `channel` appears as a property in `_links` and `stream` not `Streams`.
2. Your class `Streams` includes a `DataMember` property [`Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is an abstract class.  Of course this can't be deserialized.  Maybe you forgot to include it in your question?
3. Your `_links` dictionary is in "simple" dictionary format, i.e. [`DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.usesimpledictionaryformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You need to use this setting (.Net 4.5 or later only), or switch to [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).
4. You are using [ASCII encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is limited to the lowest 128 Unicode characters.  Use [`Encoding.Unicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.
5. [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is disposable so should be instantiated inside a [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

To fix this you need to:

1. Go to http://json2csharp.com/, post your JSON, and have it generate classes for you, then convert all the `_links` properties to `public Dictionary<string, string> _links { get; set; }`.  You should get this:

   ```
   public class Streams
   {
       public Dictionary<string, string> _links { get; set; }

       public Stream stream { get; set; }
   }

   public class Stream
   {
       public long _id { get; set; }
       public string game { get; set; }
       public int viewers { get; set; }
       public string created_at { get; set; }
       public Dictionary<string, string> _links { get; set; }
       public Preview preview { get; set; }
       public Channel channel { get; set; }
   }

   public class Channel
   {
       public Dictionary<string, string> _links { get; set; }
       public object background { get; set; }
       public object banner { get; set; }
       public string broadcaster_language { get; set; }
       public string display_name { get; set; }
       public string game { get; set; }
       public string logo { get; set; }
       public bool mature { get; set; }
       public string status { get; set; }
       public bool partner { get; set; }
       public string url { get; set; }
       public string video_banner { get; set; }
       public int _id { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string created_at { get; set; }
       public string updated_at { get; set; }
       public int delay { get; set; }
       public int followers { get; set; }
       public string profile_banner { get; set; }
       public string profile_banner_background_color { get; set; }
       public int views { get; set; }
       public string language { get; set; }
   }

   public class Preview
   {
       public string small { get; set; }
       public string medium { get; set; }
       public string large { get; set; }
       public string template { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Having done this, you can now immediately deserialize your JSON using either `JavaScriptSerializer` or Json.NET:

   ```
       string test;
       using (WebClient strJson = new WebClient())
       {
           test = strJson.DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ogaminglol");
       }

       var streams1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Streams>(test);

       var streams2 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Streams>(test);
   ```

   In both cases you will see the dictionary contents are present.
3. If you want to use `DataContractJsonSerializer` and are working in .Net 4.5 or later, you need the following helper methods:

   ```
   private static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
   {
       return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
   }

   public static T GetObject<T>(string json) where T : class
   {
       DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
       return GetObject<T>(json, serializer);
   }

   public static T GetObject<T>(string json, DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings) where T : class
   {
       DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), settings);
       return GetObject<T>(json, serializer);
   }

   public static T GetObject<T>(string json, DataContractJsonSerializer serializer)
   {
       using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(json))
       {
           return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
       }
   }
   ```

   then call it like:

   ```
       var streams3 = DataContractJsonSerializerHelper.GetObject<Streams>(test, new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true });
   ```